# Get type of property being configured from PrimitivePropertyConfiguration using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration

We have a database first approach using EF.
We use `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` to configure the mapping where T is the entity.

We often do things like `Property(t => t.EntityType).HasColumnName("EntityType_ID");` What I wish is to have an extension method on the return type of `Property()`, which is `PrimitivePropertyConfiguration` that does it for me. Like so.

```
public static class EntityTypeConfigurationExtension
{
    public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration IsForeignKey(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration propertyConfiguration)
    {
        Type typeOfEntity; //The problem is, how to know this type without passing it to this method?
        return propertyConfiguration.HasColumnName(typeOfEntity.Name + "_ID");
    }
}
```

The problem is, as you can see in the commented line, I do not see a way to get the type of the property being configured. How can I get the type of property being configured?

Comment: I assume `propertyConfiguration.GetType()` won't give you what you're looking for?

Comment: `GetType()` returns the type of object it is used on, thus it will return `PrimitivePropertyConfiguration ` in this case. See MSDN `Object.GetType` method https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah I know, bu that class has its own `GetType` method, I was kind of hopeful it was more Entity-specific: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration.gettype%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#M:System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.GetType

Comment: @silkfire All objects have this implementation. Doesn't mean it is a type specific implementation. See source code file `Object.cs` where the implementation is `public extern Type GetType();`. Thus it can't be overridden as it is not virtual. In comparison, see the implementation of GetHashCode, which can be overridden: `public virtual int GetHashCode()'.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add "_ID" to all your foreign keys you could make your own custom convention. Like this:

```
public class SuffixForeignKeyNameConvention : IStoreModelConvention<AssociationType>
{
    public SuffixForeignKeyNameConvention()
    {
    }
public void Apply(AssociationType association, DbModel model)
{
    if (association.IsForeignKey)
    {
        AddSuffix(association.Constraint.ToProperties);
    }
}

private void AddSuffix(IEnumerable<EdmProperty> properties)
{
    string result;
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        result = property.Name;

        property.Name = $"{result}_ID";
    }
}
}
```

And then apply it:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new SuffixForeignKeyNameConvention());
```

After using this convention all your foreign keys should have _ID suffix. Hope it helps.

Comment: Would this also work with a database first approach?

Comment: Sure. Entity framework support custom convention for those reasons.